# Standard superuser creation in Django admin give unrecognizable error

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

**python manage.py createsuperuser --username='donfox'**

After password is entered this is  returned

**raise TypeError("%s() got an unexpected keyword argument '%s'" % (cls.**name**, kwarg))
TypeError: User() got an unexpected keyword argument 'email'**

The User is extended from an "AbstractUser".

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    email = None
    first_name = None
    last_name = None
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'User'


   Column    |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |              Default               
--------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------
 id           | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('"User_id_seq"'::regclass)
 password     | character varying(128)   |           | not null | 
 last_login   | timestamp with time zone |           |          | 
 is_superuser | boolean                  |           | not null | 
 username     | character varying(150)   |           | not null | 
 is_staff     | boolean                  |           | not null | 
 is_active    | boolean                  |           | not null | 
 date_joined  | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove these lines:

```py
    email = None
    first_name = None
    last_name = None
```

And then remake your migrations. I'm not sure why you could add these, but `email` field is needed, as you can see in error description.